# Proof: The relative interior of a convex set is invariant under affine functions.

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, affine-geometry

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to  \mathbb{R}^m$ be an affine function, and let $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$  be convex.

Let $rint(\cdot)$ be the mapping of a set to its relative interior.

Show that:
$$
rint( f(S)) = f (rint(S))
$$

As I'm struggling with geometric proofs, I'd be especially interested in how the geometric intuition behind this helps formulating the proof (finding the right ansatz, translating intuition into formulae,...)

I guess the main idea is that the affine hull of the interior is the same as the affine hull of the set itself, and the affine hull is invariant under affine functions.

But no matter how I try to handle it, it seems to always degenerate into a lengthy messy proof with billions of technicalities.

Comment: This is a concept I hadn't heard of before, but it seems to me that you could just choose some point $p \in S$ to act as origin, turning the affine hull of $S$ into a vector space, and let $f(p)$ be the origin of the affine hull of $f(S)$, making it a vector space as well, and $f$. Then this becomes simply a statement that finite-dimensional surjective linear maps are open. Alternatively, since $S$ is convex (and since $f$ is affine, so will be $f(S)$), you can use the form of the relative interior [on this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_interior) to prove it.

Comment: @PaulSinclair The special characterization of the interior of convex sets looks useful for the proof. If I go the route of mapping every affine thing back to the responding vector spaces, I still have to proof that for any point $x\in S$, there is a cut $B_n(x,\epsilon) \cap \text{span}(S-p) \subseteq S-p$. I'd like to go about that using the SVD of the linear map... however, it doesn't really feel like the SVD helps me with how $f(S)-f(p)$ looks like

Comment: For the linear course, you are thinking too much algebra and too little topology here. To show a linear $f$ is open, you only need show that $f(D)$ is a neighorhood of $0$ for each ball $D$ about $0$. Because $f$ is surjective, for each $v$ in the codomain with $\|v\| = 1$, there is a $w$ such that $f(w) = v$, and an $a$ such that $aw \in D$. Since there are only finite dimensions, there is an $a > 0$ that works for all $v$. And therefore $f(D)$ contains the ball of radius $1/a$ about $0$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I don't think that $f$ is necessarily surjective. Which is part of the problem for me: If I take the SVD, and some singular values are 0, this effectively means that we "lose" some dimensions when looking at the deformation of the unit sphere. This would be fine, as long as we can show that the affine hull loses the same dimensions. For that again I would need to show that all points in $(U\Sigma V^T)(S)$ are projected (?) onto the same coordinate regarding the lost dimensions (?).

Comment: When I have spoken of $f$ as surjective, I meant surjective onto $\text{aff}(f(S))$. And since $f$ is affine, $\text{aff}(f(S)) = f(\text{aff}(S))$. So $f$ is surjective onto that affine hull. This affine hull, once provided with an origin, is a finite dimensional vector space isomorphic and homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^k$ for some $k$, and similarly for $\text{aff}(S)$. Showing that all surjective linear maps from $\Bbb R^{I} \to \Bbb R^k$ are open implies that $f$ must have the property you are after.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I see. Now that I understand it, that's quite an interesting way to go about the proof!

Comment: As a general rule of thumb in mathematics, when a proof gets really messy, it is because you are not thinking about it abstractly enough. You get too caught up in details that are unimportant to see what truly is. Probably the approach I've outlined still suffers from that, just not as much as yours. Of course, it is hard to figure out how to abstract the problem to remove the extraneous details. Experience is the only guide I know. The abstractions I've made are fairly standard, once you've gotten far enough to learn them.

Comment: @Sudix. Hi, sorry for gravedigging but the result you mention in the OP is very interesting. And I'm wondering if you have a source for it, and its proof? I've been stuck on proving the necessity of the KKT conditions for solutions to nonsmooth convex programming with affine constraints. Using the above theorem, the Slater CQ guarantee the existence of subgradients of the pertubation/value function associated with the optimization problem.

Comment: @ms_ This question was a reader exercise from the book "Optimierungsmethoden : Eine Einführung; von Dieter Jungnickel", Satz 2.2.13. So, the statement should hold, but the solution isn't in the book, and I don't think the book has been translated into English. I do have a proof, but it's long, messy and in German

Comment: @Sudix Thank you! Since the last comment I have found two other sources for the the theorem, both without proof. It seems to be another intuitive (convincing) result, which can be proven easily using abstract concepts, however too cumbersome to prove using elementary tools. Hope you have a good day!